# Using the mysql like statement, Auto updating upon typing

Tags: c#, mysql

So,

I want to make a query in MySQL that updates when someone types.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * WHERE 'wa' LIKE @a", con);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox1.Text);
            SDA.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        } catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace: \n" + ex.StackTrace);
            MessageBox.Show("Mysql error", "Mysql based error!");
        }
```

The one way I could think about this is by using the "Like" statement in mysql but I need to do this:

Select everything from the database, And search for a column that's value is equal to what is being typed, The problem is, I want this to show "Possible" answers, So even if they don't type it right, It will show answers that may be that they are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [SOUNDS LIKE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-sounds_like-function.php) is something that could help here

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter SDA = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * WHERE 'wa' SOUNDS LIKE @a", con);
        SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", textBox1.Text);
            SDA.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    } catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stacktrace: \n" + ex.StackTrace);
        MessageBox.Show("Mysql error", "Mysql based error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you're reply, I will try that.